# Display an Array inside Object using ng-repeat -AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my JSON object which I would like to display the name in both the parent and child array.

```
   $scope.result= [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "1002",

            "parentArray": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "name": "PRODP1",
                    "shortCode": "PRODP1"               
                }
            ]        

        }
```

I want to display Name:1002 Parent_Name:PRODP1

I tried {{item.name}} which will only display 1002.But I need to display the name of parentArray as well.

Comment: `{{ item.parentArray[0].name }}` ?

Comment: @fracz When there are more than one parentArray?

Comment: how do you want to handle if more than one parent arrays.. update your question with sample example of how should that case be displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the parentArray is also an array your going to need a nested `ng-repeat`.

If this is a large page then this may cause a performance issue.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result">
     {{item.name}}
     <div ng-repeat="innerItem in item.parentArray">
           {{innerItem.name}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`parentArray` is an...*array*, so you need to access it using an index:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in result">
    Name: {{ item.name }} Parent_Name: {{ item.parentArray.length ? item.parentArray[0].name : '' }} 
</div>
```

That's under the assumption that there is one object in `parentArray`. You might need to iterate it, or you might need to check to see if it exists depending on your requirements.